# MIME Message with Python

Tags: python, web-services, soap-client, mime, zeep

All I want to do is use the createAttachment method to attach a csv file to a request in SDM (ServiceDesk Management). Zeep is being used as the SOAP client. I keep getting an error on 'policy limit exceeded', all the discussion boards mention technologies from 10+ years ago or use code in other languages that is tough to understand for me. So far I have tried implementing some MIME stuff from the email module, but not sure how to use that for my goal either.

Here are some details on the error I am getting and what the solution is. The primary issue is that I cannot find any way to adapt the example solutions to my python code.

[documentation on the createAttachment method (and associated error)][1]

**Could not perform the operation, policy limit exceeded**

Symptom:
When using the createAttachment() web service method to attach a document to an existing request or incident, you receive this error, even when the web services policy setting for attachments is set to -1(unlimited), which is the out-of-the-box default setting. You may receive this error when calling the web service method when there are no attached files in the received SOAP message. You must attach at least one file to the SOAP message before calling the createAttachment() web service method.

Solution:
Set your SOAP implementation to support Direct Internet Message Encapsulation (DIME), and attach the file to be uploaded manually using DIME support before calling the createAttachment() method.

You can refer to the examples on how to support DIME from the $NX_ROOT\samples\sdk\websvc\java\test3_attachments directory.

code:

```
#trying to use MIME here, but not sure how to send the 'message' using the 
#createAttachment method
message = MIMEMultipart()
filename = "not_in_sdm.csv"
attachment = open("results\\not_in_sdm.csv", "rb")
p = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
p.set_payload((attachment).read())
encoders.encode_base64(p)
p.add_header(
"Content-Disposition",
f"attachment; filename= {filename}",
)

message.attach(p)

client.service.createAttachment(
        sid=sid,
        repositoryHandle=str(repoID),
        objectHandle="cr:472066",
        description="in axonius but not sdm",
        fileName="results\\not_in_sdm.csv"
    )
```